# How to get margins of a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get top and left margins of a textview which I gave hardcoded margins.

Why I'm doing this? Because I wanna loop through all the textviews I placed BELOW this textview so I can programmaticaly add radiobutton groups at these exact margins.

```
textView[0] = new TextView(context);
relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView[0].setId(1); // changed id from 0 to 1
textView[0].setText(naam[0].toUpperCase());
relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 39, 0, 0);
int tyo = relativeLayoutParams.getTop(); //Trying to get top margins.
```

Comment: Why not use LinearLayout and weight magic?

Comment: You can get position of `TextView` by `getTop()` and `getLeft()`. Check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()

Comment: Anything specific that's not working? Just see a bunch of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can simply to it the other way around. Just get the layout parameters.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
```

Then you can access the margins via global variables.

```
lp.topMargin
lp.leftMargin
lp.bottomMargin
lp.rightMargin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams;
    textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id_of_left_content);
    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, id_of_top_content);
    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, id_of_bottom_content);
    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

i hope this concept will help you